# How to save custom property to LatLng in Google Map Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to show some specific data when user mouseover the polyline in google map. I get LatLng object in in mouseover event. I would like to save custom field (index to another array with data to show) to the LatLng object, so I don't need to scan another collection.

I am not expert on Javascript. Can I add a custom property to LatLng or can I inherit/extend myLatLng object? What is the best approach?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(polyline, 'mouseover', function (event) {
    var indexOfPointInPolyline = SomeFunc(event);//I don't know how to do this properly
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a LatLng is an object, you can assign any property you want to via:

```
obj.myProperty='myValue'
```

for the given code it would be like:

```
event.latLng.someProperty='someValue';
```

But: this will not work because:

1. the mouseover-event will always pass a new LatLng-instance
2. it's also useless to implement other solutions based on the coordinates. When you log the returned values you'll see that they are always different(the accuracy will be up to centimeters or even millimeters ), it's nearly impossible for a user to touch a polyline repeatedly at the exact same point.